# How can I make a bot run forever even after I turn off my machine?

Tags: javascript, python, api, bots

I've already written out the Bot and it works perfectly fine. It's a simple bot that reads all of the new posts submitted to a subreddit and reports the posts that it finds to have violated the rules.

My question is, how to get this script to run even when my computer isn't working? Do I host it on a server?

Edit: Thank you to everyone for your suggestions. I'm new to programming and I'm very excited to see if this small bot project of mine will work out :)

Comment: "Do I host it on a server?" Yes. Your computer cannot do anything with no power...

Comment: @roganjosh wanna bet? :D

Comment: @andreihondrari .... there's a mixture of fright and intrigue here...!

Comment: you ant a VPS, they are about $5 a month and up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run on a virtual machine (VM) hosted on Google/Amazon/Microsoft cloud.

https://cloud.google.com/compute

https://aws.amazon.com/ec2

Answer (score 0):

You're right. You must host it on some VPS that runs permanently.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in no way affiliated with pythonanywhere, but try making a free account with them... Not only can you schedule python scripts to run (indefinitely) but you can also have one constantly running script as well.

Answer (score 0):

Either host it on some server or purchase a cheap PC like raspberry pi and run it from there
Technically you still have one running machine but just not your active computer